# Need help in c# code

Tags: c#, .net, generics

I have a function

```
protected void bindCurrencies(DropDownList drp)
    {
        drp.DataSource = dtCurrencies;
        drp.DataTextField = "CurrencyName";
        drp.DataValueField = "CurrencyID";
        drp.DataBind();
        drp.Items.Insert(0, new ListItem("Please Select"));
    }
```

I am binding a dropdown list using this. But sometimes I need to bind a ListBox also. I dont want to write a different function for listbox. How should I do this. I think Generics method is to be used here. But I dont have any idea about generics.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Both `DropDownList` and `ListBox` inherit from [`ListControl`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.aspx), so if you change your function to take a `ListControl` as parameter, it should work well with both types:

```
protected void bindCurrencies(ListControl drp)
{
    drp.DataSource = dtCurrencies;
    // and so on...
```

Answer (score 1):

Ask for a `ListControl` instead. Both ListBox and DropDownList inherit it, so you can use it to contain both.

Generics is (in most cases) used if you need a class *of something*. For example, a list of strings would be a List in generics.

Answer (score -2):

Pass the parameter as an Object, then simply use the object's:

```
.Getype()
```

around a select statement and cast it to that type.

Unlike the other solutions of Passing a ListControl, this will allow you to pass other controls types (and expand the logic as required).

**EDIT 1 (in response to Sebastian):**

```
 private void bindCurrencies(object PControl)
 {
    switch (PControl.GetType.ToString) {
        case "Windows.Forms.ListBox":
            Windows.Forms.ListBox ctrl = (Windows.Forms.ListBox)PControl;
            break;
        //Do Logic'
        case "Windows.Forms.DropDownList":
            break;
            //etc 
            //etc
    }
  }
```

always remember:
**KISS** (Keep It Simple Stupid)

Comment: This will make the code more complex, not simple & stupid. If he, at a later stage, needs to extend it for another object type, then he should create a matching overload. This avoids unnecessary casting and is a even more clear distinction between types and doesn't make it necessary to change (and potentially break) the working code to extend it.

Comment: I disagree, I'd rather maintain code that has a simple select case around the object type. Adding/Removing is simple as editing the select logic (not really difficult). As opposed to having multiple overloaded functions/methods dotted all over the place, which in my view is less maintainable. Using a simple select case would NOT break existing code any more than the overloaded version.

Comment: Please read 'Clean Code' from Robert Martin. He describes very good why select / switch statements are not good for maintainable code and should be avoided.

Comment: So a caller of the function can pass a String, HTTPWebRequest or even an Employee object to the function, as all subclass Object. What would the behaviour of the function be then?

Comment: Erm Case Else anyone? its no different to overloading, because behind at the root ITS doing Effectively the same thing, if X = something do Y.

Theory and practice are two different things. Still show me explicitly how the above would be any more fundermentally different to using overloading methods/functions.

Rather than downvoting without actually showing the evidence for it.

Comment: Still not convinced. By arguments provided.

Comment: @JBRWilkinson, if it doesn't match then nothing if the code does not default with anything (e.g case else) how again is this radically different to having overloaded methods or functions?